# PrimeNG schedule custom buttons

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, primeng

Can use full calendar custom buttons in PrimeNG Schedule component?

I've tried to use ElementRef by @ViewChild("calendar-id"), but I get p-shedule object type, without any fullCalendar methods.

```
customButtons: {
    myCustomButton: {
        text: 'custom!',
        click: function() {
            alert('clicked the custom button!');
        }
    }
},
```

[Custom buttons docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/customButtons/)
[PrimeNG schedule docs](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it today is make your own buttons.
It can be done with ElementRef of your calendar @ViewChild("calendar-id").

```
@ViewChild('calendar-id') calendar;
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.calendar.*;
}
```

Where * is function from PrimeNG schedule docs - [Methods](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule)

Answer (score 0):

You can get hold of the full calendar by:

```
@ViewChild('calendar-id') calendar;
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.calendar.schedule.fullCalendar('<method>');
}
```

The `schedule` member of the PrimeNG Schedule object is not documented. I discovered it from the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with the "options" property of Schedule.

```
public options : any = {};
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.options.customButtons = {
        myCustomButton: {
            text: 'myCustom',
            icon: 'fa-check',
            click: r => {console.log("clicked");}
          }
    }
```

And in the template:

```
   <p-schedule #cal [events]="events" locale="es" [height] ="750" [header]="headerConfig" [options]="options">
 </p-schedule>
```

Hope it helps